# Iterating through 2 variables to create a flag

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks generally like this:

```
Year ID Loc
2014 56 01x
2015 56 01x
2016 56 07b
2014 23 04k
2016 23 75b
2017 56 75q
2015 23 04k
2016 12 23q
2014 12 23q
2015 12 23q
```

I'm trying to create a flag for Loc changes. So for each ID if Loc is the same as the previous year the flag = 0, else flag = 1

Expected output:

```
Year ID Loc Loc_change
2014 56 01x Null
2015 56 01x 0
2016 56 07b 1
2014 23 04k Null
2016 23 75b 1
2017 56 75q 1
2015 23 04k 0
2016 12 23q 0
2014 12 23q Null
2015 12 23q 0
```

Is it possible to do this without going from a long df to wide? If so, how?

Comment: Do you not want a 4th column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shift` to make the comparisons. First, you'll need to sort the `DataFrame` and then `shift` will allow you to determine if the `ID` and `Loc` are the same as the previous year, without needing a `groupby`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Year'])

df['Loc_change'] = (~((df.ID == df.ID.shift(1)) & (df.Loc == df.Loc.shift(1)))).astype('int')

# Fix and replace the earliest year with `NaN`
df.loc[df['ID'] != df['ID'].shift(1), 'Loc_change'] = np.NaN
```

`df` is now

```
   Year  ID  Loc  Loc_change
8  2014  12  23q         NaN
9  2015  12  23q         0.0
7  2016  12  23q         0.0
3  2014  23  04k         NaN
6  2015  23  04k         0.0
4  2016  23  75b         1.0
0  2014  56  01x         NaN
1  2015  56  01x         0.0
2  2016  56  07b         1.0
5  2017  56  75q         1.0
```